# How can I prove that {$p$} is a nullset?

Tags: measure-theory

In measure theory, I don't have any idea to show that for 
$p \in \mathbb{R^n}$ the set  {$p$} is a null set.

Can somebody give me any hint about this?

Comment: First understand the definition, which depends on the context of the measure you want to give for $\mathbb{R}^n$.  The definition of "null set" here is a set of measure zero.  The product of Lebesgue measures would make this so, but other measures (with discrete weight on some point $p$) would falsify the claim.

Answer (score 3):

Let $I_\varepsilon=\left]p_1-\frac{\sqrt[n]\varepsilon}{2},p_1+\frac{\sqrt[n]\varepsilon}{2}\right[\times ...\times \left]p_n-\frac{\sqrt[n]\varepsilon}{2},p_n+\frac{\sqrt[n]\varepsilon}{2}\right[$. For all $\varepsilon>0$,
$$m(\{p\})< m(I_\varepsilon)=\varepsilon,$$
what prove the claim.

Comment: That's unusual notation. I know what you mean, but it might be bad for a beginner like OP to learn it, because it is non-standard. In particular, what does it mean to subtract a constant from a vector? To take the interval between two vectors? Both make sense, if you know what is meant, but it is abuse of notation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I think it will be better like this :-)